# Is possible to send an activity to a bot from a conversation from an other direcline client?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have a bot, a client start a conversation with it using directline 3.0.
The bot follow a waterfall flow and at one step start an external process that do something. The process, finished the task use directline to start a new connection. i would like to send a message to the bot using a specific connection as the bot receive the message and can continue the flow. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using proactive messages. There is no need to use direct line, specifically, to create a new connection to send an activity. In short, in your bot's you will create a new API that external services can ping. As part of the process, when the API is hit, a conversation reference is created that, in short, allows you to pass any received data as an activity to the bot. When the bot receives the activity, you can setup logic to determine what the bot does next.

There is a SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715944/processing-answer-to-reminder-dialog/57809361#57809361) that addresses this issue that you can reference. Additionally, you can refer to the BotBuilder-Samples GitHub [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages) for additional clarification.

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks Steven but unfortunally this is not my case, what i want is inject a message in a conversation that lookslike it is send from a client.that message should be received from the bot that continue the waterfall process (or manage it as an interruption). It seems that i can use directline to do that using directline, conversationID and the token generated in the first directline conversation. I can connect to the existing conversation using ReconnectConversation